# Is is possible to install third party android applications on windows phone 10?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

Is it possible to install third party android applications on windows phone 10?if possible then what is the easiest way?

Answer (score 4):

NO, it is not possible now.

The only possible way to do this was to run an Android subsystem within windows phone. The **Project Astoria** which allowed Windows phone to sideload Android apps by this method has been shutdown by Microsoft.

With the shutdown of Project Astoria now there is no way to run Android apps on Windows phone.

**Reference**:

1. [Microsoft officially cancels Project Astoria](http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-officially-cancels-project-astoria-bridge-porting-android-apps-windows-10-mobile)

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that's not possible. **[Windows](http://windows.com)** and **[Android](http://android.com)** are totally different operating systems, and because of that, they do not share the same types of applications. You would need an Android Emulation Software, that creates a virtual android based device, on which you can then install the third party android applications you wish to.

However, this is (currently) only possible on the full Windows operating system, not the mobile version

Comment: Project Astoria showed they aren't actually that different

Comment: But still, they are different. Similarities, yes, a lot, but they got differences. For starters, they are not built from the same base kernel. Android is UNIX based, whereas Windows is not.

As for Project Astoria, it was cancelled. Check here 

http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-officially-cancels-project-astoria-bridge-porting-android-apps-windows-10-mobile

Comment: I know it was cancelled, see the answer by 
Kolappan Nathan, but it still shows that they are not totally different. Android is a POSIX-system, rather than UNIX-based (which requires a certification that Android lacks). E.g. GNU Hurd, Gentoo/*BSD and GNU/kFreeBSD have shown that kernel isn't really relevant for being able to same program on different systems. AFAIK Android and Windows both share source code derived from FreeBSD, which also speaks against them being totally different.